# How to enable/disable button based on the number of checkboxes selected in PHP/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I know that this questions has been asked before and I tried looking up similar problems and getting some solutions but the code I used has permanently disabled the submit button :( I want it to be enabled when there are 3 boxes selected and disabled otherwise (without refreshing the page). It is a very minor problem but I can't seem to figure it out, can someone please help me find it in my code? I am also very new to these languages so any examples or descriptions will be greatly appreciated!

NOTE: My checkboxes are not made manually in HTML like in most examples on StackOverflow for this question. They are made automatically from a pre-set database in mysql.

```
    <h2>Select 3 of the following options:</h2>
        <form action="dm_courses.php" method="post">
        <div id="checkboxes">
        <?php
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";
                $hostname = "localhost";

                $dbname = "major_degrees";
                $str='';

                // Create connection
                $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

                // Check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                } 

                $sql = "SELECT degree_name FROM majors";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                $out = '';
                $cnt = 0;
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $cnt++;
                        $out .= '<input id="cb_' .$cnt. '" class="checkChange" type="checkbox" name="check" value="ch" id="checky" />' .$row['degree_name']. '<br/>';

                    }
                    echo $out;  

                } 

        ?>

    </div>      
        </form>
        <input class="btn-checkout" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" disabled="disabled"/>
        </body>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            $('.checkChange').change(function() {
                var count = 0;
                var len = $("[name='check']:checked").length;               

                $('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function() {
                    count++;
                });

                if (count == 3) {
                    $('#checkboxes input:not(:checked)').each(function() {
                        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
                    });                 
                } 

                else {
                    $('#checkboxes input:not(:checked)').each(function() {
                        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
                    });                                     
                }   

            });

        </script>

    </html>
```

Comment: `$(this).attr("disabled", true);` that should be `false`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think that code is to prevent all other checkboxes from being checkable, once they have checked 3. As in the `else` they are removing the disabled - `$(this).removeAttr('disabled');`.

Comment: @Sean You're right Sean, my mistake.

Comment: side note - `var len = $("[name='check']:checked").length;` is the same as `$('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function() { count++;});`, so you can do 1 or the other. having both is redundant code, as you now have `len` and `count` with the same value.

Answer (score 3):

After a little more head banging and hit n' try I finally got it!

I had to add the following code to enable/disable the submit button based on the number of boxes I checked off:

```
if ($(this).is(":checked") && count == 3) {
            $("#submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
            $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
```

Comment: I always admire someone who can fix things by themselves ;-) Keep on pickin' too ♫

Comment: Instead of creating a new `if/else` block, you could just add the `$("#submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");` to your `if (count == 3) {...}` and the `$("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");` to the `else {...}`

Answer (score 0):

According to jQuery API - `attributes` with `boolean` value such as `disabled` should use `.prop()` instead `.attr()`

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without
>   changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value
>   property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and
>   buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method
>   should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr()
>   method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting
>   value. - [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop1)

```
    $('.checkbox').change(function() {                
        var checked = $('.checkbox').filter(function(){
            return $(this).is(':checked');
        });
        $('.submit').prop('disabled',function(){
            return (checked.length > 2) ? false : true ; 
        });
    });
```